# Detect a change in a file of a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code in my html file:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form1" name="form1">
    <input type="button" id="button1" class="button1" value="Update 1"/>
    <input name="archivo1" type="file" class="archivo1" id="archivo1" />
</form>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form2">
    <input type="button" id="button2" class="button2" value="Update 2"/>
    <input name="archivo2" type="file" class="archivo2" id="archivo2" />
</form>
```

So, I want to detect automatically any change of any file and make different actions depending on the file selected. If I use

```
$(':file').change(function()
{
    //Code here
}
```

I want to know if I select the file named as `archivo1` or the file named as `archivo2`. Any suggestions?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like this:

```
$('input[type="file"][name="archivo1"]').change(function()
{
    //Code here
});
```

But since you're using id then you can use use that id as IDs are unique in the page.

```
$('#archivo1').change(function()
    {
        //Code here
    });
```

---

Updated as per notice as you need one change function to detect all particular file.

```
$(':file').change(function()
{
 if ($(this).attr('name')=='archivo1') {
    // ...
 }
//do check like above ...
});
```

Comment: My guess is this .[for downvote (I didnt do the downvote) ]..
The question was  "how to detect change for every file change" but your answer detects changes for a particular file type input.

Answer (score 2):

> *I want to detect automatically any change of any file and make different actions depending on the file selected*

In that case I would give them the same class (or use your original `$(":file")...`) and test the ID or name

```
$(function() {
  $(".archivo").on("change",function() { 
   if (this.id == "archivo1") { ... // or this.name =="archivo1"
   }
   else if (this.id == "archivo2") { ... // or this.name =="archivo2"
   }
 });  
});
```

You can also look at the parent or the nearest form:

```
if ($(this).parent.attr("name")=="form1"
```

or

```
if ($(this).closest("form").attr("name")=="form1"
```

Comment: This one is much better given the fact that it puts the related code in one place by using if conditions.

Comment: I agree this is best suited. But what if there's no id.

Comment: Then your code would also not work? I could change to `if ($(this).parent.attr("name")=="form1" ` too if needed